# Firefox Plugin Process quit unexpectedly on MacBook

Tags: firefox, plugins

Some plugin on my Firefox 4.0.1 'quits unexpectedly' /almost/ everytime I close my Firefox on my Macbook. Any idea which plugin may be causing this?

```
'Process:         plugin-container [666]
Path:            /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plugin-container.app/Contents/MacOS/plugin-container
Identifier:      org.mozilla.plugincontainer
Version:         ??? (1.0)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  firefox-bin [653]

Date/Time:       2011-05-18 14:23:20.759 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.7 (10J869)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          1755585 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           126
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  1015441 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   109
Anonymous UUID:                      08870CD2-D999-4942-9250-2A517A8A24BF

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x977bf922 kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x977c003c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 215
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x977bf4f9 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 163
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x977bf29e _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 240
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x977bed21 _pthread_wqthread + 390
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x977beb66 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9779909a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97799807 mach_msg + 68
2   XUL                             0x0003547b catch_exception_raise + 2283
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x977c6682 thread_start + 34

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x977be9b2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x977bef48 _pthread_wqthread + 941
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x977beb66 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x977bf922 kevent + 10
1   XUL                             0x00f56ba0 NS_InvokeByIndex_P + 165248

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x016a7fc0  ebx: 0x00e01fa0  ecx: 0xbfffd42c  edx: 0xbfffd568
  edi: 0x0280cc18  esi: 0x0280cc18  ebp: 0x0280cc20  esp: 0xbfffd45c
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010282  eip: 0x00000000   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0x1ff7 +org.mozilla.plugincontainer ??? (1.0)  /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plugin-container.app/Contents/MacOS/plugin-container
    0x4000 -     0x4ff7 +libxpcom.dylib ??? (???)  /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/libxpcom.dylib
    0x9000 -     0x9ff7 +libmozalloc.dylib ??? (???)  /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/libmozalloc.dylib
    0xc000 -  0x15e8fe3 +XUL ??? (???)  /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/XUL
 0x190f000 -  0x1914fff +libplds4.dylib ??? (???)  /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/libplds4.dylib
 0x1917000 -  0x191dfff +libplc4.dylib ??? (???)  /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/libplc4.dylib
 0x1921000 -  0x194bfef +libnspr4.dylib ??? (???)  /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/libnspr4.dylib
 0x195a000 -  0x19d5fe7 +libmozsqlite3.dylib ??? (???)  /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/libmozsqlite3.dylib
 0x19df000 -  0x19f5ff7 +libsmime3.dylib ??? (???)  /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/libsmime3.dylib
 0x1a03000 -  0x1a30ff7 +libssl3.dylib ??? (???)  /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/libssl3.dylib
 0x1a3d000 -  0x1afaff7 +libnss3.dylib ??? (???)  /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/libnss3.dylib
 0x1b1f000 -  0x1b2cff7 +libnssutil3.dylib ??? (???)  /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/libnssutil3.dylib
 0x1b37000 -  0x1becfe7  libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib 0.9.7 (compatibility 0.9.7)  /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib
0x8fe00000 - 0x8fe4162b  dyld 132.1 (???)  /usr/lib/dyld
0x90003000 - 0x9001ffe3  com.apple.openscripting 1.3.1 (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OpenScripting.framework/Versions/A/OpenScripting
0x9002d000 - 0x90030ffb  com.apple.help 1.3.1 (41)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
0x9003a000 - 0x9007efe7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3 (507.15)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
0x900e4000 - 0x900f9fff  com.apple.ImageCapture 6.0.2 (6.0.2)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
0x9028d000 - 0x90335ffb  com.apple.QD 3.36 (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
0x90336000 - 0x90341ff7  libCSync.A.dylib 545.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCSync.A.dylib
0x903af000 - 0x9041eff7  libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
0x90635000 - 0x906cdfe7  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.11 (6.5.11)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
0x906ce000 - 0x906ceff7  com.apple.Carbon 150 (152)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
0x906cf000 - 0x90700ff7  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
0x907c1000 - 0x90bf6ff7  libLAPACK.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
0x90bfc000 - 0x90bfcff7  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x90c79000 - 0x90ca1ff7  libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0 (compatibility 3.0.0)  /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x90ca2000 - 0x90ddeff7  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6.6 (1.6.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
0x90ddf000 - 0x90e17ff7  com.apple.LDAPFramework 2.0 (120.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
0x90e43000 - 0x90f44fe7  libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0)  /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x90f45000 - 0x90f87ff7  libvDSP.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
0x90f88000 - 0x90f98ff7  com.apple.DSObjCWrappers.Framework 10.6 (134)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DSObjCWrappers.framework/Versions/A/DSObjCWrappers
0x90f99000 - 0x9111bfe7  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x9111c000 - 0x91123ff3  com.apple.print.framework.Print 6.1 (237.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Print.framework/Versions/A/Print
0x91124000 - 0x911e0fff  com.apple.ColorSync 4.6.6 (4.6.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
0x911e1000 - 0x91221ff3  com.apple.securityinterface 4.0.1 (40418)  /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityInterface.framework/Versions/A/SecurityInterface
0x91222000 - 0x91244fef  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.11)  /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
0x912d5000 - 0x912e3fe7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x912e4000 - 0x91328ff3  com.apple.coreui 2 (114)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
0x91329000 - 0x9134dff7  libJPEG.dylib ??? (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
0x9134e000 - 0x91350ff7  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
0x91359000 - 0x9135cfe7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
0x913fb000 - 0x9140dff7  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework 207.10 (207.10)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
0x915e6000 - 0x915e6ff7  liblangid.dylib ??? (???)  /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x91ca0000 - 0x91cfdff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0 (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x91da0000 - 0x91db8ff7  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
0x91dcd000 - 0x91e4fffb  SecurityFoundation ??? (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
0x91e63000 - 0x91ec4fe7  com.apple.CoreText 3.151.8 (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
0x921a8000 - 0x92323fe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.4 (550.42)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x92324000 - 0x92361ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.5 (1.10.2)  /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
0x923aa000 - 0x923abff7  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent 1.1 (1)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
0x923ac000 - 0x923f9feb  com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.1 (6.1)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
0x923fa000 - 0x9243dff7  com.apple.NavigationServices 3.5.4 (182)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/NavigationServices.framework/Versions/A/NavigationServices
0x9243e000 - 0x924a2ffb  com.apple.htmlrendering 72 (1.1.4)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HTMLRendering.framework/Versions/A/HTMLRendering
0x924a3000 - 0x924a9fff  com.apple.CommonPanels 1.2.4 (91)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
0x924e4000 - 0x9259dfe7  libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0)  /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x9259e000 - 0x92909ff7  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.6.3 (227.36)  /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
0x9290a000 - 0x92c03fef  com.apple.QuickTime 7.6.6 (1756.15)  /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/Versions/A/QuickTime
0x92c37000 - 0x92c48ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.6 (1.6.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
0x92c49000 - 0x92f69ff3  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.34 (861.34)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
0x92f6a000 - 0x92fd4fe7  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0)  /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x93137000 - 0x9313bff7  libGFXShared.dylib ??? (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
0x9313c000 - 0x9314cff7  libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0 (compatibility 3.0.0)  /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
0x9314d000 - 0x9322dfe7  com.apple.vImage 4.1 (4.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
0x93c82000 - 0x93c86ff7  IOSurface ??? (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
0x93c87000 - 0x93c92ff7  com.apple.CrashReporterSupport 10.6.7 (258)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/Versions/A/CrashReporterSupport
0x93d13000 - 0x93d13ff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices 38 (38)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
0x93dc1000 - 0x93e6bfe7  com.apple.CFNetwork 454.11.12 (454.11.12)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
0x93e85000 - 0x93e8bfe7  com.apple.CommerceCore 1.0 (9)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore
0x93e8c000 - 0x93e8eff7  com.apple.securityhi 4.0 (36638)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
0x93e8f000 - 0x94096feb  com.apple.AddressBook.framework 5.0.4 (883)  /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/Versions/A/AddressBook
0x94097000 - 0x9410eff3  com.apple.backup.framework 1.2.2 (1.2.2)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Backup.framework/Versions/A/Backup
0x9410f000 - 0x941bcfe7  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x941ee000 - 0x942b9fef  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 359 (359)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
0x942ba000 - 0x942ceffb  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
0x94330000 - 0x9433cff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???)  /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x94395000 - 0x943bbffb  com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.1.2 (1.1.2)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
0x943f8000 - 0x94402fe7  com.apple.audio.SoundManager 3.9.3 (3.9.3)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonSound.framework/Versions/A/CarbonSound
0x94403000 - 0x94403ff7  com.apple.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x947ce000 - 0x9487cff3  com.apple.ink.framework 1.3.3 (107)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
0x9487d000 - 0x94898ff7  libPng.dylib ??? (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
0x94899000 - 0x949a5ff7  libGLProgrammability.dylib ??? (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x94a21000 - 0x94b25fe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8)  /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
0x94b26000 - 0x94f3cff7  libBLAS.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
0x94f3d000 - 0x951a2feb  com.apple.security 6.1.2 (55002)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
0x951a3000 - 0x951aeff7  libGL.dylib ??? (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
0x95392000 - 0x953d8ff7  libauto.dylib ??? (???)  /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x953d9000 - 0x9541cff7  libGLU.dylib ??? (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
0x9541d000 - 0x954b8ff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS 275.15.1 (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
0x954b9000 - 0x95533fff  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.2.6 (3.2.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
0x95b4d000 - 0x95c03ffb  libFontParser.dylib ??? (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
0x95c04000 - 0x95c04ff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
0x95c05000 - 0x95c38ff7  com.apple.AE 496.4 (496.4)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
0x95c39000 - 0x95c82fe7  libTIFF.dylib ??? (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
0x95c83000 - 0x95c84ff7  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.6.6 (1.6.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
0x95e31000 - 0x95f0bffb  com.apple.DesktopServices 1.5.10 (1.5.10)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
0x9601c000 - 0x9601cff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.6 (Accelerate 1.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
0x9607e000 - 0x960cfff7  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.2 (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
0x960d0000 - 0x960f1fe7  com.apple.opencl 12.3.6 (12.3.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
0x960f2000 - 0x96142ff7  com.apple.framework.familycontrols 2.0.2 (2020)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls
0x96143000 - 0x9617cff7  libcups.2.dylib 2.8.0 (compatibility 2.0.0)  /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
0x9617d000 - 0x964a1fef  com.apple.HIToolbox 1.6.5 (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
0x964a2000 - 0x9665cfeb  com.apple.ImageIO.framework 3.0.4 (3.0.4)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
0x96752000 - 0x967e4fe7  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 6.3 (312.7)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
0x967e5000 - 0x96805fe7  libresolv.9.dylib 41.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x96806000 - 0x96809ff7  libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x9775e000 - 0x97760fe7  com.apple.ExceptionHandling 1.5 (10)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ExceptionHandling.framework/Versions/A/ExceptionHandling
0x97798000 - 0x9793fff7  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.10 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x97a3d000 - 0x97a4aff7  com.apple.NetFS 3.2.2 (3.2.2)  /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
0x97a4b000 - 0x97a4bff7  com.apple.Cocoa 6.6 (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
0x97a4c000 - 0x97a5aff7  com.apple.opengl 1.6.12 (1.6.12)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
0x97a5b000 - 0x97adbfeb  com.apple.SearchKit 1.3.0 (1.3.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
0x97adc000 - 0x97ae0ff7  libGIF.dylib ??? (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
0x97ddd000 - 0x97e14fe7  libssl.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8)  /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
0x9829a000 - 0x9829fff7  com.apple.OpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
0x98355000 - 0x983f2fe3  com.apple.LaunchServices 362.2 (362.2)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
0x983f3000 - 0x98412ff7  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.2 (45.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
0x98413000 - 0x98686fe7  com.apple.Foundation 6.6.6 (751.53)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
0x98687000 - 0x987b5fe7  com.apple.CoreData 102.1 (251)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
0x9885e000 - 0x9913eff7  com.apple.AppKit 6.6.7 (1038.35)  /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
0x9913f000 - 0x99148ff7  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3 (2.3)  /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
0x99149000 - 0x99153ffb  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.11.1 (3.11.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
0x991a9000 - 0x991bdfe7  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???)  /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x991be000 - 0x999ad557  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.545.0 (???)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
0xffff0000 - 0xffff1fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???)  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Model: MacBook4,1, BootROM MB41.00C1.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 2 GB, SMC 1.31f1
Graphics: Intel GMA X3100, GMA X3100, Built-In, 144 MB
Memory Module: global_name
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x88), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.36.9)
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
```

Comment: Consider uninstalling Audio Hijack Pro temporarily. I don't like the *Instant Hijack* component in that list, especially since it's the event dispatch thread that crashed.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I manually removed the hermes folder after un-installing Audio Hijack Pro. Who knew there was such a thing. But Firefox still crashes very frequently. I have edited the crash report above.